# ModeShape WebService REST

Tags: java, rest, modeshape

I work on ModeShape 3.7.2 and i would like to use its REST API.

1. First of all I would like to know whether an API exists to **Retrieve a list of available nodes in a give workspace**?
2. Second how to interpret the syntax: `http://<host>:<port>/<context>`

- What is `<context>`?
- In the documentation they mention a `Response` format: Does this mean I should change the *config.json* file ?

Similarly to create a node: `http://<host>:<port>/<context>/<repository_name>/<workspace_name>/items/<node_path>`

What does the URI parameters stands for:

- `<context>`
- `<workspace_name>`
- `<node_path>`

Here is [the link](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODE40/REST+Service#RESTService-10.ExecuteaJCRquery) for the URL syntax.

Is there any example for each of above cases?

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no method in ModeShape's RESTful service to return *all* nodes from a repository. A repository can have millions of nodes with lots of content, so such a request would be make no sense and could have a monstrously-large response. Instead, there are methods to return some/all of the children (or descendants up to some depth) under a parent.

Secondly, the "context" is a term used in servlet-based applications, and typically refers to the location where the application is started within the server. By default this is "`modeshape-rest`", although you can change it to something else by modifying the `web.xml` in the WAR file.

The "response format" is typically JSON.

The RESTful service can access multiple repositories deployed in the same server, so in the URL format

```
http://<host>:<port>/<context>/<repository_name>/<workspace_name>/items/<node_path>
```

the variables in angle brackts(e.g., "`<repository_name>`") would be replaced with the actual value. For example, if the RESTful service is accessible on the local machine on port 8080 in the default app context "`modeshape-rest`" in the repository named "`my-repository`" with workspace "`default`", you can get the node at the path "`/a/b/c`" by making an HTTP GET request at this URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/modeshape-rest/my-repository/default/items/a/b/c HTTP/1.1
```

where the actual HTTP request might look like this:

```
GET /modeshape-rest/my-repository/default/items/a/b/c HTTP/1.1
Host: http://localhost:8080
Accept: application/json
```

and the response will be a JSON file describing the node. All of the other methods on the RESTful service use a similar pattern and are described in the [service documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODE/REST+Service+3.x).

Comment: if i wpould like to produce a frontend like a directory in windows
he will displaying the nodes(nt:folder type) on the left side of the table and the list of nodes(type nt; files) on the right. To do that he needs a list of nodes in a workspace. the following is the syntax of standard uri for webservices http://your_domain:port/display-name/url-pattern/path_from_rest_class ; and ur syntax of api differs.

Comment: couls you please give a web xml and a json file